# Does "it will only be lifting a stone to hit one's foot" mean that "it'll backfire"?

Tags: idioms

In this [article](https://english.almasirah.net.ye/post/21673/China-Draws-up-List-of-100-Instances-of-US-Interference-in-Hong-Kong?utm_source=pocket_mylist) at first paragraph there's written:

> The United States must not tolerate any force that is anti-China and stirs troubles in Hong Kong, or else **it will only be lifting a stone to hit one's foot**"

Does it mean that your hostility (e.g.) will backfire?
If it means so, why didn't they say:

> The United States must not tolerate any force that is anti-China and stirs troubles in Hong Kong, or else it will only be lifting a stone to hit **your** foot,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the quote is a Chinese official who is not a native English speaker, I would imagine. It is also possible that the official spoke in Chinese and the statement was translated by the news source.

The phrase is not one that I recognize but yes, the meaning is clear: to do something that will backfire and cause you harm. In this case the possessive pronoun should be **its** to match the beginning of the phrase:

> ... or else it [the US] will only be lifting a stone to hit *its* foot.

Comment: The US will be [shooting itself in the foot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoot-yourself-in-the-foot)? Literal translations of idioms are a minefield - French people cut off the branch on which they are sitting, Germans shoot themselves in the knee, and Italians hit their feet with their hoe.

Comment: If you shoot yourself in the foot, you fire a (figurative) gun, but the only person it harms is you. usually, when we fire a gun, we intend to harm someone else.